# How do I get the email of the logged in user in dotnet core 3 console app?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have some code that should run in a console application and does some initialization for the users. The code is in dot net core 3.1 and I need to get the current user's email out from the environment to do the task. How do I do it?

From the Environment I see that I can access the UserName, but that is basically the person's Name.

```
Environment.UserName
```

Any suggestions?

### Update 1

The assumption is that the users are logged in to Windows/Mac with their Azure Active Directory user and therefore have all necessary data which is email in here.

### Update 2

The `az login`  is the first action before running the app. Can we take anything out of that token?

Comment: Someone's email address has nothing to do with running a process.

Comment: Is this some constrained environment (Domain with Exchange, for example) where there's a "guaranteed" link between users who will be running this application and an email address?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, the code should work only for people who are a part of domain and logged in with their AzureAd

Comment: @AshkanSirous Operating system users are not "logged-in" using AzureAD. AzureAD is built on-top of OIDC which makes it specific to each process that has access to the `access_token` or `id_token` - there is nothing that's operating-system-context wide about this. Also consider the possibility that a user has multiple different AzureAD accounts that they're simultaneously accessing in different local processes.

Comment: @AshkanSirous AzureAD is not a replacement for on-prem Active Directory either (for example, a Windows desktop cannot be _domain-joined_ to an AzureAD directory).

Comment: @Dai What if the user runs "az login" before running the code. Can I get access to anything from that?

Comment: @AshkanSirous According to this article https://mikhail.io/2019/07/how-azure-cli-manages-access-tokens/ - you should be able to get a copy of the `id_token` and extract the user's email address from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preface: This answer assumes familiarity with OIDC, the structure of a JWT, and that you know the differences and responsibilities of `access_token` and `id_token`.

This answer is based on this blog post: https://mikhail.io/2019/07/how-azure-cli-manages-access-tokens/

---

When a user runs `az login` and the OIDC authentication flow is successful, then the Azure CLI (`az`) will save the current credential state to disk at `~/.azure/`. As of March 2020, the `az` executable does not attempt to encrypt or otherwise protect its cached OIDC tokens from other user processes (for better or for worse) - in this case it's a good thing - provided you don't mind malware easily nabbing your credentials.

The user's e-mail address (at least, their e-mail address associated with their AzureAD account) will be inside their OIDC identity token JWT (`id_token`) - this doesn't seem to be cached by `az login` so you'll need to use an OIDC client to use the plaintext `access_token` extracted from the `~/.azure/accessTokens.json` file to request the OIDC `userinfo` (User Profile Resource) from AzureAD's OIDC service (assuming the `access_token` grants you access to the User Profile Resource in the first place).

But assuming you *do* have access to the User Profile Resource, the user's e-mail address will be [in the `email` claim property](https://auth0.com/docs/users/normalized/oidc).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the current operating system's user's e-mail because it isn't defined.

I think you're referring to UPN-style usernames as seen in Windows Active Directory domains which are of the form `{userName}@{fqdn}`, e.g. `alice@corp.bob.com` (where `corp.bob.com` is the fully-qualified Active Directory domain name). A UPN is often, but not always, a user's e-mail address because of Microsoft Exchange Server's default configuration.

...but UPNs don't exist on platforms that don't use Active Directory, such as embedded systems and most Linux installations. You'd have to use the LDAP library in `System.EnterpriseServices` to look it up (perhaps using ADSI).

Comment: Unfortunately for us the username is never the email so I cannot do username@domain, but thanks for System.EnterpriseServices. Let me take a look :)

Comment: @AshkanSirous `System.EnterpriseServices` is for ADSI/LDAP, it won't help you with an OIDC-based service like AzureAD.